# Three consecutive integers which are power of prime but not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

Does there exist three consecutive positive integers such that each of them is the power of a prime i.e., is there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $n=p^i$, $n+1 = q^j$ and $n+2 = r^k$, where $p$, $q$ and $r$ are primes and $i,j,k >1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Catalan conjecture...................

Comment: In short, for those who don't know what this is: the only instance of consecutive prime powers is the pair (8, 9).

Comment: @Théophile Actually Catalan's conjecture (now a theorem) gives the stronger result that the only instance of consecutive integer powers (prime integers or not) is the pair $(8,9)$.

Comment: @Ethan Indeed, I see that you are right. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Catalan is an overkill. $q$ **needs** to be $2$.

Answer (score 14):

Note that either both $n$ and $n+2$ are even, or both are odd. If both are even, then $p=r=2$  and we are done. If they are both odd, $n+1$ is even and $q=2$. So
$$n+1=2^j\implies n=2^j-1=p^k$$
Now look at [When is $2^n\pm1$ a perfect power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500616/when-is-2n-pm-1-a-perfect-power).